# reCaptcha widget not always displayed when used within AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, recaptcha

I use AngularJS and tried to embed reCaptcha widget within component. Component is loaded from `templateUrl`. Widget after a few refreshes is not displayed, and when using back button of browser is not displayed at all.
When I place recaptcha widget in layout template(index.html) no problem occurs.
I tried vcRecaptcha directive but problem stays the same. I'm looking for a solution so that the widget always loads properly even in components.
I think the problem may cause additional request that is sent to download the component's template. (`templateUrl`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by race conditions, ie recaptcha script was loaded before component with `g-recaptcha` widget. Injecting script in component controller solved problem.

```
module.component("component_name", {
    templateUrl: "component_name/component_name.html",
    controller: function(){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("src", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js");

        var el = document.getElementsByTagName("component_name")[0];
        el.appendChild(script);
    }
})
```

Now script is loaded always after component.